# Failure of wave theory in explaining photoelectric effect

Tags: waves, photoelectric-effect

What property of waves makes it unable to explain to the photoelectric effect, and how does that property make the wave theory fail in explaining the photoelectric effect?

Comment: This is pretty easily answered by looking up 'photoelectric effect.'  Did you do any research?

Comment: see my answer with links to a similar question here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567420/classical-wave-theory-and-the-photoelectric-effect/567429#567429

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question lacks basic prior research.

Answer (score 1):

If light was only a wave increasing the intensity of light would have increase the kinetic energy of photo electrons as intensity of the wave represents it's energy but it was found out that kinetic energy is unaffected by the change in intensity , it  simply increases the number of electrons (all with the same energy) hitting the metal.

Comment: That's misleading.  It's not so much the kinetic energy as it is the critical (photon) frequency at which bound electrons are freed from their orbitals.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft what's misleading?

Comment: If you are at the photoelectron wavelength, then the electron is freed from the atom with no kinetic energy.  It might then gain energy via phonons, or from a local electrical field, etc.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft So ...? I don't understand ur point . Which part of my answer is misleading ?